# NextJS Deployment: TypeError breaks fetch-routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I'm having a super funky NextJS 13.4 Error that I'm having trouble identifying the source of. What I know is summarised below:

- The problem appears only **after** using `npm run build` & `npm run start`, not during `npm run dev`
- The problem appears both locally and on Vercel servers
- I have a vague hunch it's related to Webpack
- The problem breaks all client-side fetch routing (in other words, the whole point of Next13

```js
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'textContent')
    at Object.<anonymous> (main-4f563ee09e593a2f.js:1:8408)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at n (17-bbe337a8760cd758.js:1:134)
    at u (17-bbe337a8760cd758.js:1:331)
    at 17-bbe337a8760cd758.js:1:390
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (17-bbe337a8760cd758.js:1:272)
    at Object.Q (main-4f563ee09e593a2f.js:1:9011)
    at t.initialize (main-4f563ee09e593a2f.js:1:7055)
    at 8577 (main-4f563ee09e593a2f.js:1:15791)
```

Here's the error creating function, which is not a part of my own codebase, but seems to be related to Next/navigation:

```js
 function Q() {
            return (Q = g(function*() {
                arguments.length > 0 && void 0 !== arguments[0] && arguments[0],
                a = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("__NEXT_DATA__").textContent),
                window.__NEXT_DATA__ = a,
                h = a.defaultLocale;
                let e = a.assetPrefix || "";
                if (n.p = "".concat(e, "/_next/"),
                x.setConfig({
                    serverRuntimeConfig: {},
                    publicRuntimeConfig: a.runtimeConfig || {}
                }),
                l = N.getURL(),
                D.hasBasePath(l) && (l = I.removeBasePath(l)),
                a.scriptLoader) {
                    let {initScriptLoader: e} = n(6507);
                    e(a.scriptLoader)
                }
                o = new O.default(a.buildId,e);
                let t = e=>{
                    let[t,n] = e;
                    return o.routeLoader.onEntrypoint(t, n)
                }
                ;
                return window.__NEXT_P && window.__NEXT_P.map(e=>setTimeout(()=>t(e), 0)),
                window.__NEXT_P = [],
                window.__NEXT_P.push = t,
                (u = R.default()).getIsSsr = ()=>r.isSsr,
                i = document.getElementById("__next"),
                {
                    assetPrefix: e
                }
            })).apply(this, arguments)
        }
```

There seems to be basically no one else having this issue, here's my package json:

```json
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "fetch-img": "node scripts/downloadImages.js",
    "export": "next export",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@contentful/rich-text-html-renderer": "^16.0.2",
    "@contentful/rich-text-react-renderer": "^15.16.2",
    "@contentful/rich-text-types": "^16.0.3",
    "@next/font": "13.1.6",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.52.1",
    "axios": "^1.3.3",
    "contentful": "^9.3.3",
    "encoding": "^0.1.13",
    "eslint": "8.34.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.1.6",
    "firebase": "^9.17.1",
    "next": "13.1.6",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dnd": "^16.0.1",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^16.0.1",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-firebase-hooks": "^5.1.1",
    "sass": "^1.58.3",
    "stripe": "^12.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "postcss": "^8.4.23",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack": "^5.83.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.1"
  }
```

So far I've tried:

- Upgrading packages
- Deploying to different environnments
- Using different browsers

But the problem persists... Instead of pretty client-side fetching of the next page the application goes through a full reload on every navigation.

Edit: Formatting

Comment: OK I don't think this has to do with any of your packages. It's related to your code. `textContent` is a property of a DOM node. Are you querying the DOM and reading its content in your code? As a start I would check the built file and see if the mentioned line `main-4f563ee09e593a2f.js:1:8408` has anything that I can relate to. If that doesn't work I would start commenting parts of my code until I identify which part is causing the issue

Comment: @AhmadAlfy The thing is, that line is a part of Nextjs, I've never written it nor anything like it. As far as I can gather it's a part of the <Link /> element from next/navigatiojn...

Answer (score 1):

### I have a solution!

So, it turns out I was somewhat right about the package.json. The reason for this error was that this project was created with next version `13.1` and this issue was solved in the current version. For anyone in the future encountering this problem: Simply upgrade Next.JS Specifically to the latest version.

Here's an excerpt from my new `package.json`

```json
[...]
    "encoding": "^0.1.13",
    "eslint": "8.34.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.1.6",
    "firebase": "^9.17.1",
    "next": "^13.4.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dnd": "^16.0.1",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^16.0.1",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
 [...]
```